# XGBOOST-Multi class prediction. Prediction matrix is set of probabilities for classes. How to perform confusion matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

I have used XGBOOST for multi-class label prediction.

This is a multi-label prediction. i.e my target value contains 8 classes and I have about 6 features that I am using since they are very highly correlated to the target value.

I have created my prediction data set. I have converted into the data frame from matrix using as.data.frame

I wanted to check the accuracy of my prediction. I am not sure how since col names changes and there are no levels in my data set. All data types I am using are integers and numerics.

```
 Response <- train$Response
 label <- as.integer(train$Response)-1
 train$Response <- NULL

 train.index = sample(n,floor(0.75*n))
 train.data = as.matrix(train[train.index,])
 train.label = label[train.index]`
 test.data = as.matrix(train[-train.index,])
 test.label = label[-train.index]

 View(train.label)

 # Transform the two data sets into xgb.Matrix
 xgb.train = xgb.DMatrix(data=train.data,label=train.label)
 xgb.test = xgb.DMatrix(data=test.data,label=test.label)




  params = list(
          booster="gbtree",
          eta=0.001,
          max_depth=5,
          gamma=3,
          subsample=0.75,
          colsample_bytree=1,
          objective="multi:softprob",
          eval_metric="mlogloss",
          num_class=8)

    xgb.fit <-xgb.train(
    params=params,
    data=xgb.train,
    nrounds=10000,
    nthreads=1,
    early_stopping_rounds=10,
    watchlist=list(val1=xgb.train,val2=xgb.test),
    verbose=0
      )

   xgb.fit



  xgb.pred = predict(xgb.fit,test.data,reshape = T)
  class(xgb.pred)
  xgb.pred = as.data.frame(xgb.pred)

   """
```

Now I got my prediction probabilities in the below form, Since 8 classes I have 8 probabilities. I don't know which probability belongs to which variable.

```
1   0.12233257  0.07373134  0.044682350 0.0810693502    0.06272415  0.134308174 0.066143863 0.415008187
```

I want to convert them to meaningful labels. which I am not able to do. To perform confusion matrix

Comment: what is class(xgb.pred), and why did you include the response variable in train.data ?

Comment: I am asking because I cannot reproduce your error using some simulated data. Can you also do dput(head(train,20)) and paste the output?

Comment: dput(head(train,5))
structure(list(Medical_History_23 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Medical_Keyword_3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Medical_Keyword_15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    BMI = c(0.323007976, 0.272287744, 0.428780429, 0.352437744, 
    0.424045645), Wt = c(0.148535565, 0.131799163, 0.288702929, 
    0.205020921, 0.234309623), Medical_History_4 = c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), Ins_Age = c(0.641791045, 0.059701493, 0.029850746, 
    0.164179104, 0.417910448), Response = c(8L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L
    )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame") @StupidWolf

Comment: Please edit your question and include a sample of your data (1 row is enough) and the output. It's hard to navigate in comment section.

Comment: @StupidWolf i Just updated the question. I am having trouble with the confusion matrix. I have 8 classes so xgb.pred gave me 8 probabilities. I am not sure which probability belongs to which class. if i can decode and assign max prob to a single class. I can go ahead do the confusion matrix. may be i am missing a step or two. Can you please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MTT updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your data is something like this:

```
train = data.frame(
  Medical_History_23 = sample(1:5,2000,replace=TRUE), 
  Medical_Keyword_3 = sample(1:5,2000,replace=TRUE), 
  Medical_Keyword_15 = sample(1:5,2000,replace=TRUE), 
  BMI = rnorm(2000), 
  Wt = rnorm(2000), 
  Medical_History_4 = sample(1:5,2000,replace=TRUE), 
  Ins_Age = rnorm(2000), 
  Response = sample(1:8,2000,replace=TRUE))
```

And we do the train and test:

```
library(xgboost)
label <- as.integer(train$Response)-1
train$Response <- NULL
n = nrow(train)
train.index = sample(n,floor(0.75*n))
train.data = as.matrix(train[train.index,])
train.label = label[train.index]
test.data = as.matrix(train[-train.index,])
test.label = label[-train.index]
xgb.train = xgb.DMatrix(data=train.data,label=train.label)
xgb.test = xgb.DMatrix(data=test.data,label=test.label)

params = list(booster="gbtree",eta=0.001,
          max_depth=5,gamma=3,subsample=0.75,
          colsample_bytree=1,objective="multi:softprob",
          eval_metric="mlogloss",num_class=8)

xgb.fit <-xgb.train(params=params,data=xgb.train,
    nrounds=10000,nthreads=1,early_stopping_rounds=10,
    watchlist=list(val1=xgb.train,val2=xgb.test),
    verbose=0
      )

xgb.pred = predict(xgb.fit,test.data,reshape = T)
```

Your prediction looks like below, each column is the probability of being 1,2...8

```
> head(xgb.pred)
         V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8
1 0.1254475 0.1252269 0.1249843 0.1247929 0.1246919 0.1248430 0.1248226 0.1251909
2 0.1255558 0.1249674 0.1250741 0.1250397 0.1249939 0.1247931 0.1248649 0.1247111
3 0.1249737 0.1250508 0.1249501 0.1250445 0.1250142 0.1249630 0.1249194 0.1250844
```

To get the prediction label, we do

```
predicted_labels= factor(max.col(xgb.pred),levels=1:8)
obs_labels = factor(test.label,levels=1:8)
```

To get confusion matrix:

```
caret::confusionMatrix(obs_labels,predicted_labels)
```

Of course this example I have will be low accuracy because there's no useful information in the variables but the code should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Same order as your label.
For example:

```
0.415008187
```

is the probability of happening 8th class and so on.